# Inserción de datos en tiempo rea lC# Hikvision-reloj biométrico-SQL server con dos tablas que tienen relación

Tags: c#, sql-server, biometrico

He creado una tabla en mi base de datos para que los eventos en tiempo real de mi reloj biométrico se inserten. Tengo una función que me muestra los eventos en tiempo real por medio de la consola

```
private void MsgCallback(int lCommand, ref HCNetSDK_Events.NET_DVR_ALARMER pAlarmer, IntPtr pAlarmInfo, uint dwBufLen, IntPtr pUser)
{

   Event EventInfo = hcNet.ProcessAlarm(lCommand, ref pAlarmer, pAlarmInfo, dwBufLen, pUser);

    if(EventInfo.Success)
      Console.WriteLine(EventInfo.Time.ToString()+" EventDescripcionMinor: " + EventInfo.Minor_Type_Description
          + " EmployeeNo: " + EventInfo.Employee_Number + " DeviceIp: " + EventInfo.Device_IP_Address);
    else
        Console.WriteLine(EventInfo.Exception);
}
```

Lo que deseo ahora es poder insertar esos valores que obtendo desde el evento `MsgCallbacken` mi tabla que cree:

```
IdDispositivo Código del dispositivo de la tabla EQ_DispositivoBiometricoRondaSeg
Fecha                                   Fecha y hora del evento (Marcaje)
CodigoEmpleado             Código del empleado que marco
FechaCreacion                  Fecha y hora del sistema
Temperatura                     si el reloj no lo trae colocar 0
Acción                         nombre del evento que envía el reloj
```

Nota: El `IdDispositivo` es la relación con otra tabla que hace referencia a que reloj pertenece el marcaje, o sea es la referencia del reloj que se esta usando por así decirlo. Lo que se plantea es registrar los eventos en tiempo real en mi tabla

```
Esta es la otra tabla(la utilizo para el mantenimiento de los relojes)
IdDispositivo (llave, la base de datos genera el código)
Nombre       (Nombre del dispositivo)
DireccionIP  (dirección ip)
Puerto       (numérico mayor igual a 0, predeterminado 80)
NoPuerta     (Numérico mayor o igual a 1, no se puede repetir)
NoPlan       (Numérico Mayor o igual a 1, predeterminado 1)
Usuario      (usuario para conectar al dispositivo)
Clave        (clave de usuario, usar mascara para no ver la clave)
TipoUsuario  (Nombre de tipo d usuario)
Asistencia   (Bit, 1 o 0, predeterminado 0
```

Al intentar registrar en la DB la primera tabla(el campo `IdDispositivo`) lo llena de esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como lo estoy tratando de realizar:

```
private void InsertarEventoEnDB(Event evento)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        Guid idDispositivoBiometrico = ObtenerIdDispositivoBiometrico(evento, connection);

        string query = "INSERT INTO EQ_BiometricoFacialDescarga_Seg (IdDispositivo, Fecha, CodigoEmpleado, FechaCreacion, Temperatura, Accion) " +
                       "VALUES (@IdDispositivo, @Fecha, @CodigoEmpleado, @FechaCreacion, @Temperatura, @Accion)";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdDispositivo", idDispositivoBiometrico); // Cambiado a GUID
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", evento.Time);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodigoEmpleado", evento.Employee_Number);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaCreacion", DateTime.Now);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Temperatura", 0);
            //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodigoAccion", ObtenerCodigoAccion(evento));
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Accion", evento.Minor_Type_Description);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}

private Guid ObtenerIdDispositivoBiometrico(Event evento, SqlConnection connection)
{
    // Implementa la lógica para obtener el IdDispositivo asociado al evento
    // Puedes utilizar la información del evento y las consultas a tu base de datos según sea necesario

    // Ejemplo: Supongamos que el IdDispositivo está relacionado con el campo IdDispositivo en la tabla EQ_DispositivoBiometricoRondaSeg
    string query = "SELECT IdDispositivo FROM EQ_DispositivoBiometricoRondaSeg WHERE Nombre = @Nombre";

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        // Ajusta según la lógica para obtener el nombre del dispositivo
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", ObtenerNombreDispositivo(evento));

        // Ejecuta la consulta y obtén el resultado
        object result = command.ExecuteScalar();

        // Convierte el resultado a Guid (asumiendo que IdDispositivo es de tipo GUID)
        return result != null ? (Guid)result : Guid.Empty;  // Ajusta según tu lógica
    }
}
private string ObtenerNombreDispositivo(Event evento)
{
    // Implementa la lógica para obtener el nombre del dispositivo desde el evento
    // Puedes usar propiedades del evento como Device_IP_Address u otros campos que identifiquen el dispositivo

    // Ejemplo: Supongamos que el nombre del dispositivo está en la propiedad Device_IP_Address
    return evento.Device_IP_Address;
}
```

Comment: Muestra los datos que tienes en `EQ_DispositivoBiometricoRondaSeg `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Funcion para obtener el ID del reloj,

```
private Guid ObtenerIdDispositivoBiometrico(Event evento, SqlConnection connection)
{
    // Implementa la lógica para obtener el IdDispositivo asociado al evento
    // Utiliza la información del evento para identificar el dispositivo 
    string query = "SELECT IdDispositivo FROM EQ_DispositivoBiometricoRondaSeg WHERE DireccionIP = @DireccionIP";

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        // Ajusta según la lógica para obtener la dirección IP del dispositivo desde el evento
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DireccionIP", ObtenerDireccionIPDispositivo(evento));

        // Ejecuta la consulta y obtén el resultado
        object result = command.ExecuteScalar();

        // Convierte el resultado a Guid (asumiendo que IdDispositivo es de tipo GUID)
        return result != null ? (Guid)result : Guid.Empty;  // Ajusta según tu lógica
    }
}
   

// Función para obtener la dirección IP del dispositivo desde el evento
private string ObtenerDireccionIPDispositivo(Event evento)
{
    // Se pueden usar propiedades del evento como Device_IP_Address u otros campos que identifiquen el dispositivo
    return evento.Device_IP_Address;
}
private void MsgCallback(int lCommand, ref HCNetSDK_Events.NET_DVR_ALARMER pAlarmer, IntPtr pAlarmInfo, uint dwBufLen, IntPtr pUser)
{
    Event evento = hcNet.ProcessAlarm(lCommand, ref pAlarmer, pAlarmInfo, dwBufLen, pUser);

    if (evento.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{evento.Time} EventDescripcionMinor: {evento.Minor_Type_Description} EmployeeNo: {evento.Employee_Number} DeviceIp: {evento.Device_IP_Address}");

        // Llama a la función para insertar el evento en la base de datos
        InsertarEventoEnDB(evento);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(evento.Exception);
    }
}
```